# Docker flask restful app using host files

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am creating Restful API using python, flask and docker. I have already created image and run container.

```
FROM python:2.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

When i run: `docker run -p 5000:5000 flaskrestful` and go the localhost:5000 i got the expected response:

```
{'hello': 'world'}
```

After editing method that return me `json` above, nothing is changed. I want the server in docker container to automatically reload after changing the project files on host machine.

Is there any way to do that? I have tried with volumes but to edit anything inside I need to use root privileges and I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do is to run container with several flags:

```
docker run -it --name containerName --mount type=bind,source=host directory,target=container direcotory -p host_port:container_port image_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["gunicorn","app:app","-w","2","-b","0.0.0.0:5000","--timeout","400"]
```

Add up please to the last line of your Dockerfile. Don't also forget to include gunicorn in your requirements.txt